# Samsung tablet hangs a lot

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, tablet

My Samsung Galaxy Tablet 2 10.1 model no.P7500 is giving me a lot of hanging problems. Most of the times, the touch is unresponsive and touch operates automatically and makes me land in unwanted places. The device is not rooted and I had done a factory reset and also flashed stock ROM but the problem continues.